# Split list of Integers in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

It is as simple as it looks.

How to split List of integers in apache camel without making camel complains when he tries to split the `list<Integer>` into `Byte`s instead!

The code looks like:

```
....
.transform().message(this::doSomeProcessing)      // doSomeProcessing returns List<Integer>
.filter(simple("${body.size} != 0"))
.split(body())
.to(someRabbitMQExchange())
....
```

And here's the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert number [9901400] of type [java.lang.Integer] to target class [java.lang.Byte]: overflow
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in `rabbitmq` endpoint, it needed the message to be converted to `json` first.

so, I just added `.marshal().json()` before `.to(someRabbitMQExchange())` and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try comment o avoid the filter, run de app and validate again, tell me that happen later of this.